# C Programming - Copy File Buffer and Write to File

Tags: c

I'm making some small changes to a preexisting application.  The app is writing lines of text to a buffer and then flushing the buffer.  I'm not sure when it actually writes the text to the file, but I'm trying to copy everything in that buffer and write a copy of it all out to a completely different file.

Below is the last line of writing to the preexisting buffer before it eventually calls `fflush()`.

```
fprintf(_log, "-- FINAL TEXT LINE --\n");
```

Below is my code that I'm using in an attempt to copy that buffer to a separate file which is dynamically named according to the log time. This `custom-%ld.log` does not already exist and needs to be created.

```
char tmp[sizeof(_log)];

sprintf(tmp, "custom-%ld.log", (long int)lf->time);

FILE *fp1, *fp2;
char a;

fp1 = _log;

fp2 = fopen(tmp, "a");
if (fp2 != NULL) {

    do {
      a = fgetc(fp1);
      fputc(a, fp2);
    } while (a != EOF);

    fflush(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}

fflush(_log);
```

I'm sure my mistakes are very basic, but I don't know what I'm doing.  I've tried dozens of suggestions on other websites, and suggestions here from other questions, but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: `char tmp[sizeof(_log)];` doesn't look good, considering the `fp1 = _log;` and `FILE *fp1, *fp2;` afterwards. Also, `a = fgetc(fp1);` is wrong for `char a;`

Comment: You've described what you're trying to achieve, but what's the actual question for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a few mistakes in here.

This will allocate a buffer of 4 or 8 bytes depending on the word size of your computer. 'sizeof' is a compile time directive that gives you the size of the underlying type.

> char tmp[sizeof(_log)];

So do this instead (where 100 is just a big enough number to hold the result):

> char tmp[100];

Next using a char for 'a' will not be able to hold the EOF value. Use int.

> int a;

By fixing the definition of 'a' your loop is now not infinite, but it will eventually write the constant EOF to the file, which will be some garbled character. Change it like so:

> while ((a = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) {
>     fputc(a, fp2);
>   }

So in the end you should have:

```
char tmp[100];

sprintf(tmp, "custom-%ld.log", (long int)lf->time);

FILE *fp1, *fp2;
int a;

fp1 = _log;

fp2 = fopen(tmp, "a");
if (fp2 != NULL) {
    while ((a = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) {
        fputc(a, fp2);
    }

    fflush(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
}

fflush(_log);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.  This is the answer with 2 exceptions.  I ended up using "w" within fopen() and removed the fflush(fp1) since I'm already flushing it when I flush _log.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing `EOF` to file *before* checking it with

```
do {
    a = fgetc(fp1);
    fputc(a, fp2);
} while (a != EOF);
```

You could try

```
int a;                          // make sure you have the correct type
while((a = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
    fputc(a, fp2);
}
```

`EOF` is not (except some legacy formats) part of the file. It is an indicator returned by file reading functions.

Note that `fflush(fp1);` is undefined behaviour when `fp1` is opened for input.

You say `"custom-%ld.log"` does not already exist yet you open it with

```
fp2 = fopen(tmp, "a");
```

Which would append, if you forgot to delete a previous version. To make sure it is a new file, open with

```
fp2 = fopen(tmp, "w");
```

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions.  Rather than fflush(fp1) should I be using just fclose?

Comment: I don't know why you are trying to flush the input file in this partial code snip. That is usually only done (by other means) if you want to discard input you cannot use (such as unsatisfied input for `fscanf` so you can move on). But since `fp1 = _log;` you have attempted to flush the same input twice!